# .vimrc remap jj <ESC> not working - taken literally

Tags: vim

in my .vimrc I have the following
`imap jj <ESC>`

When I type jj however while in insert mode, instead of exiting insert mode VIM literally types `<ESC>` into my document. Hitting the escape button does take me from insert to command mode, as expected.

How do I remap jj to allow me to exit insert mode?

I am using vim 7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:help key-notation` has this to say:

> If you want to use the full <> notation in Vim, you have to make sure the '<'
>   flag is excluded from 'cpoptions' (when 'compatible' is not set, it already is
>   by default).
>
> ```
> :set cpo-=<
> ```

This might have been accidentally set in your Vim session, and after a Vim restart the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

`:set nocompatible` worked for me. I think vi-compatibility mode may have been the problem.